# How to get the names of all png files in a folder using GetFilesAsync - WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, text-files, getfiles

I have a folder called AllPage. It has a number of png files. I m trying to retrieve the names of all the files from the folder using GetFilesAsync and apparently it retrieves nothing! :(

This is how I tried

```
        IStorageFolder dataFolder = await local.CreateFolderAsync("AllPage", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
```

**EDIT**

```
        var obj = await dataFolder.GetFilesAsync();
        var temp = obj[0];
        var temp1 = obj[1];            
        return true;
```

obj gives me COM component. :( I'm so confused.

Comment: Have you tried awaiting it? `var obj = await dataFolder.GetFilesAsync();`

Comment: @KooKiz Yes I tried, it gives the same COM object. When i put var temp = obj[0]. Sorry there is a small mistake in what i had mentioned. The folder contains one text file and the remaining ones are png files.

Comment: yup I guess I got the answer. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I retrieved the file names :)

```
        IStorageFolder dataFolder = await local.GetFolderAsync(App.ALL_PAGE_FOLDER);
        IEnumerable<IStorageFile> files = await dataFolder.GetFilesAsync();

        foreach (IStorageFile anyfile in files)
        {
            if (anyfile.Path.EndsWith(".png"))
            {
                var name = anyfile.Name;
            }
        }
```